# Understanding ELMo's number of presentations

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, allennlp, elmo

I am trying my hand at ELMo by simply using it as part of a larger PyTorch model. A basic example is given [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/master/tutorials/how_to/elmo.md#using-elmo-as-a-pytorch-module-to-train-a-new-model).

> This is a torch.nn.Module subclass that computes any number of ELMo
>   representations and introduces trainable scalar weights for each. For
>   example, this code snippet computes two layers of representations (as
>   in the SNLI and SQuAD models from our paper):

```
from allennlp.modules.elmo import Elmo, batch_to_ids

options_file = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/elmo/2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_options.json"
weight_file = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/allennlp/models/elmo/2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway/elmo_2x4096_512_2048cnn_2xhighway_weights.hdf5"

# Compute two different representation for each token.
# Each representation is a linear weighted combination for the
# 3 layers in ELMo (i.e., charcnn, the outputs of the two BiLSTM))
elmo = Elmo(options_file, weight_file, 2, dropout=0)

# use batch_to_ids to convert sentences to character ids
sentences = [['First', 'sentence', '.'], ['Another', '.']]
character_ids = batch_to_ids(sentences)

embeddings = elmo(character_ids)

# embeddings['elmo_representations'] is length two list of tensors.
# Each element contains one layer of ELMo representations with shape
# (2, 3, 1024).
#   2    - the batch size
#   3    - the sequence length of the batch
#   1024 - the length of each ELMo vector
```

My question concerns the 'representations'. Can you compare them to normal word2vec output layers? You can choose how *many* ELMo will give back (increasing an n-th dimension), but what is the difference between these generated representations and what is their typical use?

To give you an idea, for the above code, `embeddings['elmo_representations']` returns a list of two items (the two representation layers) but they are identical.

In short, how can one define the 'representations' in ELMo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Section 3.2 of [the original paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.05365.pdf).

> ELMo  is  a  task  specific  combination  of  the  intermediate layer representations in the biLM. For each token, a L-layer biLM computes a set of 2L+ 1representations

Previously in Section 3.1, it is said that:

> Recent  state-of-the-art  neural  language  models compute a context-independent token representation (via token embeddings or a CNN over characters) then pass it through L layers of forward LSTMs.  At each position k, each LSTM  layer  outputs  a  context-dependent  representation. The top layer LSTM output is used to predict the next token with a Softmax layer.

To answer your question, the representations are these L LSTM-based context-dependent representations.